# Cant bind to ajax events on a select_tag in Rails 3.1 & JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, events

Having trouble with Rails UJS and binding to ajax events

I have some JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#MySelect").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function() { 
      alert('bread crumb');
   });       
 });
```

and a select tag in the view:

```
< % = select_tag "MySelect", options_for_select(controller.get_Mylist), "data-remote" => true, "data-url" => "/update_my_list", "data-type" => :json % >
```

I can't work out why my ajax events aren't getting caught. I can catch the change event for this select tag if I simply change the binding item from 'ajax:beforeSend' to 'change'.

I know the ajax request is getting fired because I can see it in the logs. says it rendered fine with a 200 response for the update_my_list method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Forgiveness please..

I believe the snippet of code I shared with you all was fine however. It was what i wasn't showing that was interfering with how I wanted it to work.

I guess after migrating to Rails 3.1, I left this lying around:

< script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> < / script >

Turns out removing it fixed the problem. Must have been a conflict :)